# SQL Case select

Tags: sql, sql-server

is it possible to select from a different table, based on the results of a case select in mssql?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: The [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) does not control flow.  I wince to think of how you want to use this...

Comment: From reading other comments I think you should be a bit more precise about what you're trying to do.  I suspect you may be going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select
  ConditionalValue = (Case When something Then Table1.Value Else Table2.Value End),
  ...
From
  Table1
  ...
  Table2
```

For more details, we'll need more details.

Answer (score 4):

You can build dynamic SQL and then execute it.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM '

CASE Condition
    WHEN 1 THEN @SQL = @SQL  + 'TABLE '
    ELSE @SQL = @SQL  + 'TABLE1 '
END

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: nice one, i think i understand where you are going with this one, ill give it a whirl

Comment: I do not like dynamic SQL for a few reasons. Make sure you parameterize all user input.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the tables have some 1-to-1 relationship, you can join them, then return a column from A or from B depending on a case operator for the column. Barring that, you can use procedural code (TransactSQL) to test the condition that determines the table from which to select, and call one select statement or the other that return identical columns, but each is pointed to a single table. If the tables have similar schemas and you're querying them from a program, you can manipulate the string representation of the command based on the condition you wish to check. Lastly, you can UNION two queries, each pointing at a different table, with a WHERE clause on each subquery that evaluates the condition and does not return any rows if false.

Comment: `you can use procedural code (TransactSQL) to test the condition that determines the table from which to select`.  Research `parameter sniffing` before doing something like this.  Not that it can't be done, but it can have huge performance implications.

Comment: thanks for the detailed responce, the 2 table do have a relationship. i want to count the amount of entries in one table that meet a criteria based on the results of a query into the other table

Answer (score 1):

THe IF statment controls flow not CASE. If you want to select values from one of two differnttables that are both in the joins in the query, CASE is appropriate, otherwise use IF.